# How to allow some html tags and disallow others?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc 1.0 it is possible to add a `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to an `ActionResult`. Is it possible to allow some HTML (<p>,<a>) and disallow other HTML tags (<script>)? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own attribute similar to "ValidateInput" the would check the input and allow custom tags.

Have a look at this for help [Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx)

Comment: I thought it was possible using the default ValidateInput function. The signature says: ValidateInputAttribute.ValidateInputAttribute(bool enableValidation, <strong>Named Parameters...</strong>)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own attribute similar to "ValidateInput,"

See here for Custom Attributes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056.aspx

It's just a class that inherits from the Attribute base class. You'd create a method within the class that would use regular expressions (www.regular-expressions.info) to detect the "bad" tags -- the input is the content of the page, run the expression, if there's a match, then throw an error, or return the error code, whatever you choose.